# Epson printer connects to the network that is not listed

Tags: networking, printer, network-printer

I have an Epson L3250 printer. I set the printer connect to network `192.168.1.0` for wireless printing.

Then I set static DHCP for IP address. After few days, why does that printer connect to network `192.168.0.0`?

The network `192.168.0.0` is not listed in my network.

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks.